# magento 1.9 how to show product in home page like category page

Tags: category

I use this code and show **the product** of this **category**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but I want to show content of home page(product of category)  looks like category page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this code at cms home page Content tab

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

After that go to **System->configuration->Permissions->Blocks**

*Add New Block* **catalog/product_list** over there and *Is allowed* **'Yes'**.

You need to whitelist tag onwards in magento since 1.7.